# WCF ODATA client error appearing after building with Visual Studio 2012

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2012, client, .net-4.5, odata

Started seeing this error message for WCF ODATA calls after we migrated our build server to VS 2012:

> The operation '*********Async' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.

The error was resolved by installing .NET 4.5.  Very strange since all of our projects target .NET 4.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI for people running into this error, it can ALSO be an issue of WCF and Async calls.  .net 4.5 supports Async and .net 4.0 does not.  If you are getting this error on an Async operation, it is likely because you are in a .net 4.0 environment and somehow ended up with a reference added as .net 4.5.  To resolve the issue, either re-add your reference with .net 4.0, or install .net 4.5.

My issue was that I couldn't install .net 4.5 on an old 2003 server.  Removing and re-adding the reference and then re-deploying to the server fixed the issue.